# Android Event Time Listener

Tags: android

i would to implement a method with a SPenTouchListener of SPen SDK. The listener works fine but i would to capture data of touch (coordinates, etc.) every 10ms from the first touch of the user since the user press another button. How i can do this?
Thi is part of code of the listener:

```
public boolean onTouchPen(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            updateTouchUI(event.getX(), event.getY(), event.getPressure(), event.getAction(), "Pen");
            }

private void updateTouchUI(float x, float y, float pressure, int action, String tool){
    mX.setText("X : " + String.format("%.2f", x));
    mY.setText("Y : " + String.format("%.2f", y));
    mPressure.setText("Pressure : " + String.format("%.3f", pressure)); 
}
```

In other words i want to call the *updateTouchUI* every 10ms for since the user press a button in the activity. Also i want to capture timestamp every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Handler`

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
public void updateUI() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 10); //10ms
    }  

    /**
     * Background Runnable thread
     * */
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
      updateTouchUI (param...); //Your function

               // Running this thread after 10 milliseconds
               mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);
           }
    };
```

And add  `updateUI()` in onClickEvent of your desire `Button`

Comment: do you get new reads on the position of the touch every 10ms or do you just copy the ones from the last event with this?